# Sinch push notification problems

Tags: android, parse-platform, sinch

Hey i have tried all the tutorials i could find online talking about allowing sinch sdk to manage android push notifications using

```
     @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();

    if (currentUserId != null && !isSinchClientStarted()) {
        startSinchClient(currentUserId);
        Log.d("pp", currentUserId);
    }

 //        make sure you have created a SinchClient
//        if (SinchHelpers.isSinchPushIntent(broadcastIntent)) {
//            NotificationResult result = sinchClient.relayRemotePushNotificationPayload(broadcastIntent);
//        }

    broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

public void startSinchClient(String username) {
    sinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(this)
            .userId(username)
            .applicationKey(APP_KEY)
            .applicationSecret(APP_SECRET).environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT).build();

    sinchClient.addSinchClientListener(this);

    sinchClient.setSupportMessaging(true);
    sinchClient.setSupportManagedPush(true);
    sinchClient.setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground(true);

    sinchClient.checkManifest();

//        sinchClient.registerPushNotificationData("goodies-59e3".getBytes());

    sinchClient.start();
}

private boolean isSinchClientStarted() {
    return sinchClient != null && sinchClient.isStarted();
}

@Override
public void onClientFailed(SinchClient client, SinchError error) {
    broadcastIntent.putExtra("success", false);
    broadcaster.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

    sinchClient = null;
}
```

but to no avail and when i try to the method above i get no result, i dont even kknow if anything is happening, i get no notification when i try to send a message to someone who is not currently on the app. I have been on this problem for weeks now please i would appreciate any work around

Comment: post your code what you have tried.

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi i have updated my Question, please help me out here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below steps are as follows:

1) Permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<permission android:name="com.sinch.messagingtutorial.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sinch.messagingtutorial.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

2) Add Google play service lib to your project and also create Project Id of your project on google play developer console

3) Using your project ID, declare the following in LoginActivity.java onCreate:

```
final GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    class RegisterGcmTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        String msg = "";
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                msg = gcm.register("your-project-number");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
            }
                return msg;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListUsersActivity.class);
            serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessageService.class);
            serviceIntent.putExtra("regId", msg);
            startActivity(intent);
            startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
```

For more detail please refer https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/send-push-notifications-android-messaging-app-using-gcm/ link

and For Demo refer Github Link https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/send-push-notifications-android-messaging-app-using-gcm/

Comment: Thanks @Anjali i have tried to implement this tutorial and after that when i open the app for the first time i get no error but when i exit the app i get the error with logs saying 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

This refers to the line saying:: regId = intent.getStringExtra("regId"); pls can i get some help on that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd make sure your app has the following permissions to receive push messages (and the WAKE_LOCK permission to keep executing after the push is received).

`<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<permission android:name="YOUR.APP.PACKAGENAME.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="YOUR.APP.PACKAGENAME.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>`

I'd also recommend that your review this link to receive GCM push notifications: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/#manifest

Hope this helps!